# CordovaWebView.loadUrl opens external link in broswer

Tags: android, cordova-3

I am passing a url into my application and calling loadUrl on a CordovaWebView.  Anytime I try with an external URL it opens the link in an external browser application.  I need it to remain in my application.

```
myCordovaWebView.loadUrl("http://google.com");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
myCordovaWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
          view.loadUrl(url);
          return true;
           }}); 
myCordovaWebView.loadUrl("http://google.com");
```

Comment: Perfect.  This solves the problem and give me a framework for editing the entire loading process.